# Why is catch block optional?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I have the following code

```
public static void nocatch()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Which gives the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type CustomException
```

My Question is why was it designed that the catch block is optional, when there is no way of getting around not having a catch?

---

From finally()'s perspective, I understand that

`finally` should have atleast a `try` block, `catch` is optional. The point of finally blocks is to make sure stuff gets cleaned up whether an exception is thrown or not. As per the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

> A finally clause ensures that the finally block is executed **after the try block and any catch block** that might be executed, no matter how control leaves the try block or catch block.

---

**Edit:**

By adding a return in the finally block, compiler does not give the error WHY?!

```
public static void nocatch()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    finally
    {
        return; //By adding this statement, the compiler error goes away! Please let me know why
    }
}
```

Comment: The question as to "why" is pretty much opinion based; the fact is that Java is (as far as I know) the only language to have the notion of checked exceptions, and it appears that your `CustomException` is such an exception. And there are rules for dealing with checked exceptions.

Comment: It allows you to implement the `finally` clause.  It won't "hide" the exception.

Comment: Going to throw try with resources (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in here for omiting finally as well ;)

Comment: Doesnt matter what is a `CustomException`. For argument sake lets consider just `Exception`

Comment: As to why there's the concept of "checked exceptions", you can blame that on a guy named Goodenough.  He wrote an article on exception handling and the Java guys copied it.

Comment: @HotLicks: By "blame" you do, of course, mean "give due credit and reverence for one of the outstanding features of the Java language and environment." ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - No, I mean blame ;)

Comment: [Neil's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131397/why-use-try-finally-without-a-catch-clause/131400#comment328505_131400) has a, practically, good example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My Question is why was it designed that the catch block is optional, when there is no way of getting around not having a catch?

Yes there is: Declare that the method throws the exception:

```
public static void nocatch() throws CustomException
{
    try
    {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

`try/finally` without `catch` is to ensure that you clean up anything you need to clean up, even if you aren't handling the exception yourself. (Be sure not to allow any *other* exception to be thrown from within `finally`, or you'll hide the primary exception.)

Here's an example to play with ([live copy](http://ideone.com/sA5sse)):

```
private static class CustomException extends Exception {
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Calling nocatch(false)");
        nocatch(false);
    }
    catch (CustomException ce) {
        System.out.println("Caught CustomException for false case");
    }
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Calling nocatch(true)");
        nocatch(true);
    }
    catch (CustomException ce) {
        System.out.println("Caught CustomException for true case");
    }
}

public static void nocatch(boolean foo) throws CustomException
{
    try
    {
        if (foo) {
            System.out.println("Throwing");
            throw new CustomException();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("In finally");
    }
    System.out.println("Reached outside the try/finally block");
}
```

Output:

```
Calling nocatch(false)
In finally
Reached outside the try/finally block
Calling nocatch(true)
Throwing
In finally
Caught CustomException for true case
```

As you can see, the `finally` block's code runs regardless of whether an exception occurred, but the code *after* the `try/finally` doesn't.

---

Re your follow-up asking why adding `return` within the `finally` makes the error go away:

```
try
{
    throw new CustomException();
}
finally
{
    return; // <=== Makes the compiler happy (but don't do it!)
}
```

Interesting edge case! It's because the code in the `finally` block **always runs**, and so you'll always return rather than throw, hiding the exception that occurred. E.g., this is the sequence:

1. `throw new CustomException()` throws the exception, which transfers control to the `finally` block
2. Code in the `finally` block issues a normal return from the method

This hides the fact the exception occurred; in effect, you've "handled" the exception (without actually handling it) via the `finally` block. In general, this isn't a good idea; use `catch` to handle exceptions, or declare them on the method so calling code can handle them.

Comment: if you have a throws clause, there is no need for a try{} in the first place. But If I understand correctly, in the above case we are adding try block only to have the finally... is that right?

Comment: @codeMan: Right: The purpose is to say "I'm going to do this stuff, which may throw an exception; whether it does or not, be sure to run my `finally` code so I can clean up afterward." Which is why the standard `try` **must** be followed by either `catch` or `finally` (or both) (try-with-resources can stand completely alone, because it has *implicit* `catch` and `finally` clauses).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. There is one more little thing that I cannot fathom upon.. I have edited my question, can you please take a look.

Comment: @codeMan: Added a bit to the bottom: It's because if you do that, your method no longer throws at all.